# PageModel and IValidatableObject - validation is not invoked

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages, ivalidatableobject

I tried to implement `IValidatableObject` on my Razor Page model in ASPNET Core 2.

I was surprised that the Validate method was not invoked. Moving all `[BindableProperty]`s to a new type implementing `IValidatableObject` did work, however.

**Is this the only way?**  It would be nice to be able to implement `IValidatableObject` directly on my `.Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.PageModel` type.

Comment: Looks like enabling this is being considered for ASP.NET Core 3.0: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/7919

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?